# How do I delete a coupon Programmatically in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a coupon programmatically in my custom woocommerce plugin. Now I would like to delete the coupon whenever the plugin is deactivated.

How should I do that.

I'm adding the coupon code on **register_activation_hook**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
$coupon_data = new WC_Coupon('YOUR_CODE');
if(!empty($coupon_data->id))
{
    wp_delete_post($coupon_data->id);
}
```

Comment: It works for the first time. When I tried deactivating and activating the plugin it doesn't work. So what I did was to manually write the code in my register_deactivation_hook to delete the coupon from Post table from the database.

Comment: where did you write your `register_deactivation_hook` hook ????
in plugin or theme ???

Comment: Its in my plugin file.

Comment: Make sure that, your code only run when you `deactivate` your plugin...not at activation...